# javascript navigator objects not showing in alert box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've tried many time to solve this but, I'm get entire code in alert box.

Can anyone solve this?

```
function detail(){
        var txt="";
        txt ="<p>Browser CodeName: "+ navigator.appCodeName +"</p>";
        txt +="<p>Browser Name: "+ navigator.appName +"</p>";
        txt +="<p>Browser Version: "+ navigator.appVersion +"</p>";
        txt +="<p>Cookies Enabled: "+ navigator.cookieEnable +"</p>";
        txt +="<p>Browsr Language: "+ navigator.language +"</p>";
        txt +="<p>Browser Online: "+ navigator.onLine+"</p>";
        txt +="<p>Platform: "+ navigator.platform +"</p>";
        txt +="<p>User-agent header: "+ navigator.userAgent +"</p>";
        txt +="<p>User-agent language: "+ navigator.systemLanguage +"</p>";

        alert(txt);
    }
```

When user click on button it shows alert with navigator details of browser

```
    <input type="button" value="Detail" onclick="detail()"/>
```

Comment: what do you want to achieve instead?

Comment: dear @pronox I just try to learn navigation of BOM. in this code I include all detail of the navigator function. when user click on button , than function calls, it will show alert box with all detail of browser using navigator, but here alert box display code insted of detail.

Comment: So what do you want to do ? You have shown an alert `alert(txt);` what do you expect then ?

Comment: I just try to learn navigation of BOM. in this code I include all detail of the navigator function. when user click on button , than function calls, it will show alert box with all detail of browser using navigator, but here alert box display code insted of detail. @RohitSubedi

Comment: I just try to learn navigation of BOM. in this code I include all detail of the navigator function. when user click on button , than function calls, it will show alert box with all detail of browser using navigator, but here alert box display code insted of detail. @user3110424

Comment: @iDevTechnolab you mean you want to cut all html markup and just display text in alert box or what?

Comment: BOM what is this ?? I really dont understand your question. What do you want to achieve?

Comment: You need to play with `DOM` try `document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].innerHTML=(txt);` in place of `alert(txt);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presume you wanted each item on a new line hence the `<p>` tags. You can't put HTML markup in an alert box but you can use `\n`.

```
function detail(){
    var txt="";
    txt ="Browser CodeName: "+ navigator.appCodeName +"\n";
    txt +="Browser Name: "+ navigator.appName +"\n";
    txt +="Browser Version: "+ navigator.appVersion +"\n";
    txt +="Cookies Enabled: "+ navigator.cookieEnable +"\n";
    txt +="Browsr Language: "+ navigator.language +"\n";
    txt +="Browser Online: "+ navigator.onLine+"\n";
    txt +="Platform: "+ navigator.platform +"\n";
    txt +="User-agent header: "+ navigator.userAgent +"\n";
    txt +="User-agent language: "+ navigator.systemLanguage +"\n";

    alert(txt);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Me3xq/

Answer (score 1):

Did a quick research not sure if this can meet your requirement.. You can use Unicode characters and the escape characters \n and \t. An example:

```
alert( 
    'This is an alert with basic formatting\n\n'
    + "\t• list item 1\n"
    + '\t• list item 2\n'
    + '\t• list item 3\n\n'
    + 'Simple table\n\n'
    + 'Char\t| Result\n'
    + '\\n\t| line break\n'
    + '\\t\t| tab space'
);
```

or if you want to use something more perfect use the modal div popup .. here is the [link](https://jqueryui.com/dialog/)

Answer (score -1):

```
alert(message)
```

message -- Specifies the text to display in the alert box, or an object converted into a string and displayed

So the coming result is correct. You can't write HTML code in alert.

If you want to write it to DOM use:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].innerHTML=(txt);
```

Comment: Seriously, are you sure this is what is he is asking for?

Comment: Hi, Thanks it also Perfect.. now I understand that alert box do not accept any tag